# Automatically click recaptcha box in electron with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, electron, captcha

Im attempting to setup an autoclick function in my javascript code that will click a recaptcha in my electron window when called. Ive taken a look at a google chrome extension that automatically clicks recaptchas on a page successfully and their simple code is on github. When I tried to implement their code into my electron window it is never successful. Is this something to do with electron or is it something im just doing incorrectly?

This is their code.

```
let isRecaptchaFrame = () => {
  return /https:\/\/www.google.com\/recaptcha\/api2\/anchor/.test(window.location.href);
};

let captchaInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (isRecaptchaFrame()) {
    clearInterval(captchaInterval);
    document.getElementsByClassName('recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark')[0].click();
  }  
}, 500);
```

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out

Comment: what did you figure out? Can you add your findings!

Answer (score 0):

Electron is built on Node.js so you don’t have access to the window api. Try this: 
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window